# $\mathcal{B} = \{ B(x) \subseteq \Bbb{R^n} : x \in \Bbb{Q^n}$ and $0 < \ \epsilon \ \in \ \Bbb{ Q}$ } is countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

and a basis for $\Bbb{R^n_{ususal}}$

Attempt at a solution:
$\mathcal{B}$ is countable since $\Bbb{Q^n}$ is countable and $x \in \Bbb{Q^n}$.(Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think $\epsilon \in \Bbb{Q}$  matters, since if there are only countably many x, there can only be countably many $B \in \mathcal{B}$ regardless of what $\epsilon$ is). To show $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis we need to show two things:

1.$\mathcal{B}$ covers $X = R^n$, since rationals and irrationals are arbitrarily close, so $\bigcup\mathcal{B} = X$.

2. Given $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}, B_1 \cap B_2$ is also $\in \mathcal{B}$ .Let $\epsilon = r_1 - r_2$, this is a rational since the sum/difference of two rationals is again a rational, moreover between two rationals: a < b, $\exists p \in \Bbb{Q}: p \in (a,b)$ So we have that if $B_1 \cap B_2$ is non-empty then, $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$.
   So we have that $\mathcal{B}$ is countable and a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n_{usual}$  which also implies that  $\Bbb{R}^n_{usual}$ is 2nd countable.

Edit:
I want to define a bijection to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, let $f = ((f_1,...,f_n),f_{n +1})$ where $f_i: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$, let $x = (f_1,...,f_n)$ and $f_{n + 1} = \epsilon$, then f is a bijection:  $f:\Bbb{N}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ Is this the correct way of defining a bijection?

To show that given $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}, B_1 \cap B_2$ is also $\in \mathcal{B}$, let z be in $B_1 \cap B_2$, pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} min((z-r_1), (z-r_2), r_1 - r_2)$ where $r_1, r_2$ are radius of $B_1, B_2$ respectively. If z is a rational then let $r_3$ = largest rational distance between (z, z + $\epsilon$], if z is an irrational, then pick a rational q between (z,z + $\epsilon$)  this exists since between any two reals there is a rational, pick r_3 in the same manner as before. Then $B_{r_3}(q) \subseteq B_1 \cap B_3$ and $ \in \mathcal{B}$

I would really appreciate feedback, thank you

Comment: You really need $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$ to be countable. If you take just one $x$ but $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, the set in non countable.

For 2, you don't need that $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, because it may be the case that the intersection isn't a ball. What you need is to find a ball, centered somewhere, with rational radius, contained in the intersection.

Comment: @Luis I added some changes, I'm not too sure about the way I defined the bijection though